# Tapestry t:palette NPE when options selected

Tags: java, tapestry

I have a palette who's model is populated by a user search of customers. This works perfectly when searching initially, however once a customer is selected and the user continues to search for more customers to select a NPE is thrown.

Code from .tml

```
    <t:palette t:id="custSelect" model="customerModel" t:encoder="stringValueEncoder" 
                         availableLabel="Search Results"  t:selected="custSelected" value="custSelected">
                         ${custSelected}  

                 </t:palette>
```

Coresponding .java

```
Object listResults(List<TbgWebIntCustomer> customers) {
    log.debug("LISTRESULTS");
    customerList = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (customerList != null) {
        customerList.clear();
        if (request.isXHR()) {
            ajaxResponseRenderer.addRender(resultZone);
        }
    }
    String result;
    log.debug("LISTRESULTS2 " + customers.size());

    for (int i = 0; i <= customers.size() - 1; i++) {
        log.debug("counter: " + i);

        TbgWebIntCustomer currentCustomer = customers.get(i);

        String customerNumber = currentCustomer.getCustomerId();
        // Remove leading zeros

        String customerName = currentCustomer.getLocationName();

        result = customerNumber + " - " + customerName + " - "
                + currentCustomer.getCity();
        log.debug(result);
        customerList.add(result);

    }

    log.debug("LISTRESULTS3");
    log.debug("customer list size: " + customerList.size());
    getCustomerModel();
    log.debug("customermodel after customerlist: "
            + getCustomerModel().size());

    if (customerList.size() == 100) {
        resultsMessage = "Search returned over 100 results. Showing top 100.";
        log.debug(resultsMessage);
    } else {
        String numResults = Integer.toString(customerList.size());
        resultsMessage = "Search returned " + numResults + " customers";
        log.debug(resultsMessage);
    }
    log.debug("LISTRESULTS4");
    log.debug("customerModel returns at i 0: " + getCustomerModel().get(0));

    return request.isXHR() ? resultZone.getBody() : null;
}
```

Note: getCustomerModel() returns getCustomerList().

I understand that NPEs in Palette happen when one of the selected options is not present in the model you passed to it however I can't identify where it is I'm doing this. I can post setupRender() code if necessary, just trying to keep OP compact.

Comment: Could your tell us at which line did the NPE throw?

Comment: @MincongHuang  at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.util.SelectModelRenderer.option(SelectModelRenderer.java:49)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.components.Palette$SelectedRenderer.render(Palette.java:165)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.RenderPhaseEventHandler$1.render(RenderPhaseEventHandler.java:96)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.RenderQueueImpl.run(RenderQueueImpl.java:72)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.PageRenderQueueImpl.render(PageRenderQueueImpl.java:124)

Comment: @MincongHuang or in the .tml @   xmlns:p="tapestry:parameter"